# What happens to Rails AR objects when you drop a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know that you can drop a table by running an irreversible migration to drop_table.

However, what happens to the AR records that currently exist prior to the table drop? Are they destroyed?

Comment: yes, AR records (instances of ActiveRecord::Base) are the representation of a row in your DB's table (unless it is a new record not saved yet). Dropping a table destroys all its content, irreversibly, and the associated ActiveRecord::Base class (ex: `User`) will complain if you query the DB but the table does not exist

Comment: These objects are in memory. Nothing happens to them (they will even tell you they are persisted); however the table and data they reference no longer exists in the database which will cause issues if you try and interact with the database layer at all (e.g. save, delete,etc.). In addition "destroy" is a rails word for delete with call backs and has nothing to do with the database per se (other than the obvious DELETE statement)